# Pandas dataframe cumsum splited by zero

Tags: python, pandas

There is a df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1], columns = ['A'])
```

How to add a B column, its elements are based on the cumsum of cells in column A value of 1, and if it encounters 0, then cumsum start over.

Expected result:
[image]

```
>>> print(df)
A   B
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   2
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
0   0
0   0
1   1
1   2
1   3
0   0
1   1
1   2
```

Comment: `df['B'] = df.groupby(df['A'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()` or `df.groupby(df['A'].eq(0).cumsum())['A'].cumsum()` if you have values other than `1`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect it to be so easy.